# Can characters play multiple Adventure Paths?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If a Pathfinder Adventure Path is designed for level 1 characters (and ends with them being level 15), how are characters supposed to play in multiple paths?

(If that is even an option, or do you *need* to recreate characters for each adventure?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, people create new PCs for new Adventure Paths.  The 6 adventures in each AP are designed to go from level 1 to level ~15, in order.

That's not mandatory; I've run some AP mashups, combining slower than usual advancement with modding adventure levels up or down to make it happen. For example, my current Reavers campaign used the first two chapters of Second Darkness, a bunch of other modules including the Freeport Trilogy from Green Ronin, and will have pieces of Skull & Shackes and Razor Coast APs in it by the time we're done. But yes, typically, the AP model is designed for new level 1 characters customized to the location/plot/genre at hand.

This is generally for the best; mostly people have grown tired of their character after 15 levels and are interested in trying something else out.  If not, there are high level modules and ideas at the end of each AP on taking it farther. It's rare in gaming that people play "the same character for their whole life," though I have heard of home campaigns that have done that. Usually you try out new characters, and GMs put together new plotlines from the lower level stuff they *haven't* yet used.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you run AP after AP, the PCs won't advance much til the end of an AP. Of course you can expect the beginning of each AP to be a slaughter fest as the PCs are way beyond the recommended level range.

Answer (score -2):

I dont run them with Pathfinder, I modify them for D&D 4E. Without giving plot point xp and just combat xp characters are only 8th level at the end of one AP. If you wanted to do Curse of the Crimson Throne and lead into Carion Crown you introduce the Professor in Korvosa near the beginning, maybe have him return around the middle and then inform the players of his death after saving Korvosa.

No reason why you cant do more than just one if you work the intro of the next one into the current setting properly.